# Sending an email from a batch job that is defined in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a batch job that runs outside any request, response scope.

I would like to be able to define the email content in JSP since the email content is primarly an HTML document with placeholders for values.

Basically, I would like to be able to run a JSP from a static method.

Is this possible? The solutions online suggests having access to a request and response, implementing httpservlet. Can I not fake these?

I know this is a difficult question, but it would feel good to find a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP as a view technology is inseparably tied to the HTTP request/response cycle. You're better off using some other templating engine such as [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) to generate the e-mail message body.

Comment: Yes, I have seen FreeMarker, and it seems interesting.. However, I am not sure if its ok to pull in another jar file. Architects often try to limit such usage... :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fire just a HTTP request on the JSP and get its HTTP response.

```
InputStream response = new URL("http://localhost/context/page.jsp").openStream();
// ...
```

But, JSP is definitely the wrong tool for the job. You don't need to send an unnecessary HTTP request. Rather use a template engine or make use of a plan text/html file with [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API.

Comment: Yes, its unnessary to create a HTTP request. However, in tests, one could mock a request right? It should  be possible to create such a request and use that.. although I am new to JEE so I have never mocked anything, so I wouldnt know...